# Google App Maker: How to access properties of an item bound to widget?

Tags: google-app-maker

In the App maker, I have created a datasource with several items which I'm displaying on a table. When the user clicks on an item, a pop up comes up with the properties of the item the user clicked bound to the widget. Once the user clicks the save button on that pop up, I want to get the id of the current item in a server script. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Just to confirm, do you want to pass the id of the selected item to a server script?

Comment: That is correct @Morfinismo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use an asynchronous operation. The [**official documentation**](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/client#asynchronous_operations) explains how you can achieve this. Basically, you need to do something similar to this:

Let's say that on a server script you have the following:

```
function doSomething(id){
    //do something
    if(!id){
        throw Error("Id is missing");
    }        
    return "ID = " + id;
}
```

Then on the **SAVE** button you need to have something like this on the **onClick** event handler:

```
var id = app.datasources.**yourDataSource**.item.id;
google.script.run.withFailureHandler(function(error){
    console.log(error);
).withSuccessHandler(function(response){
    console.log(response);
}).doSomething(id);
```

I hope this helps!